# Setting protocol which inherits from another protocol as associated type produces error

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm trying to learn protocols and associatedtypes. I have couple of protocols which declare associatedtypes, starting with:

```
protocol MasterViewModel {
    associatedtype Item: AWMediaItem
...
}
```

`AWMediaItem` is another protocol

```
protocol AWMediaItem {
    var name: String { get }
    var source: AWMediaSource { get }
}
```

And `AWAlbum` is yet another protocol which inherits from AWMediaItem

```
protocol AWAlbum: AWMediaItem {
    var albumName: String { get }
...
}
```

For some reason, in a class implementing `MasterViewModel` protocol, I cannot set the AWAlbum to be the `Item`.

```
final class AlbumsMasterViewModel: MasterViewModel {
    typealias Item = AWAlbum // Error
...
}
```

The warning I get is

> 1. Possibly intended match 'AlbumsMasterViewModel.Item' (aka 'AWAlbum') does not conform to 'AWMediaItem'

If I understand correctly, all `AWAlbum's` will implement `AWMediaItem` so why is this not working?

Comment: Where is the implementation of  `name` and `source` in `AWMediaItem`? Even in a protocol based environment somewhere the protocol requirements must be implemented.

Comment: In structs/classes that implement this protocol. I don’t think it makes any difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write

```
final class AlbumsMasterViewModel<Item: AWAlbum>: MasterViewModel {
    
}
```

I assume that when you write :

```
    typealias Item = AWAlbum // Error
```

you want `AlbumsMasterViewModel`'s item to conform to your `AWAlbum` protocol but you just create a typelias meaning that `Item` is **just** an alias for  `AWAlbum` .

If you want to use a type alias you need a concrete type conforming to `AWMediaItem`, not a protocol inheriting from it. eg :

```
class ConcreteAlbum: AWAlbum {
    var albumName: String
    var name: String
    var source: AWMediaSource
    ...    
}

final class AlbumsMasterViewModel: MasterViewModel {
    typealias Item = ConcreteAlbum // No Error
}
```

### Edit

if you want to use `AlbumsMasterViewModel` with multiple `Item` types you can also declare it that way :

```
final class AlbumsMasterViewModel<Item: AWMediaItem>: MasterViewModel {
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help in my case. AWAlbum is a protocol and few classes conform to it so I can display them all in my view. Creating another class adds another unnecessary layer IMO. I don't understand why my solution can't work, inheriting from another protocol guarantees that the base protocol requirements will be fulfilled. What a shame, thanks anyway

Comment: Since I **tested** my code and you **did not** share any type conforming to `AWAlbum` I **had** to create a dummy concrete type for my example to work. You just have to replace `ConcreteAlbum` by any of the few classes you already have, it's a mock object, not part of the solution ;)

Comment: Yes, but I have, let’s say, objects of type AlbumA and AlbumB and both types conform to AWAlbum protocol. I don’t understand how can I use both types by using protocol and typealias :/

Comment: You can't use a typealias, but you can use a generic type

Comment: Seems like it, but generic type won't help in my case. My goal is to create a protocol that would serve as a basic structure on how to create view models in my app, every view model would use different protocols, like AWAlbum, AWArtist, AWPlaylist etc. 
All those protocols inherit from AWMediaItem but they have to handle them a bit differently, for example when creating table view cells, so using generics would mean checking the exact type at every step and that would be a mess. It's a shame that typealias is so restricted, it doesn't make any sense IMO. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well my original answer was `final class AlbumsMasterViewModel<Item: AWAlbum>: MasterViewModel` but you did not seem to like it. Did you even try it ? if you have an `ArtistsMasterViewModel` class you can write `final class ArtistsMasterViewModel <Item: AWArtist >: MasterViewModel`... but hey if you're not convinced you never will be :)

Comment: Anyway you question only mention a warning I suggest you edit it and add all the necessary details and explain what you trying to do so that somebody can help you

Comment: I did try your solution as soon as you posted it and it raised a lot of errors :/
The `MasterViewModel` has few default methods that use the `Item` and those methods would show errors after I tried your code. I don't think it's possible to mix associatedtypes and generics in this way. I will add a new question explaining my problem better

Comment: It's not surprising that you have errors in your code after modifiying it. Especially if you make a non-generic class generic. As I said you should either edit this post to give feedback and share the errors you get (debugging details), or create a new one but I do not see how you'll do what to want w/o generics or multiple conforming classes. but to be clear `typealias Item = AWAlbum` will probably never work like you think it should if `AWAlbum` is a protocol

Comment: Yes and it sucks really, that you can't use protocol as typealias

Comment: but you actually **don't** need to, generics are great ;)